# Iframe code doesnt display website

Tags: iframe

When I put into html file this code, it does not show website.

```
<iframe src="https://www.ge-tracker.com/names/claws">
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

It is because your target site to put into the iframe does not allow itself to be loaded into an iframe that is hosted on a a different domain. It uses the X-Frame-Options http header to advise this to any browser that requests it.

You can examine this by looking at the error console in your chosen browser.

For instance, using Chrome, you will see:

> Refused to display 'https://www.ge-tracker.com/names/claws' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'.